# 15N NMR simulation with orca software

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I would like to simulate J(15N-1H) couplings with orca. By default, the software uses the 14N isotope for NMR nitrogen simulation. In the program, in the xyz input, I added M 15 on the line of the N to declare the 15N isotope for the simulation. In the report, I can see it has been taken into account (mass =15) but in the coupling constant part of the report, nitrogen is refered to as 14N. Is there another way to set the 15N information onto the program?

Comment: Please include more information for your question, e.g. the input file. Your question won't be well received here as it is heavy on technical doing and very light on the actual chemistry. Once you've improved your question, I suggest migrating it to [mattermodeling.se]. Please do not cross post it there.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン This might fit (better) at Material Modeling but I think questions about simulation of chemical spectra are well suited for our site.

Comment: @Buck agreed, in general.